# Capistrano creating new DB for every deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, capistrano

At the moment I have Capistrano deploying to a server which is set up as a development environment.

However, everytime I run `cap deploy`, it doesn't keep the database at all, so every deployment ends up with a fresh database, completely empty. I have to run `cap deploy:migrations` to set up the DB, but the issue here is that there is an individual DB for each deployment.

I figure I could change `database.yml` to use a path such as `../../db/development.sqlite3` for the DB but this would mean I then have to copy that change locally too, and moving my DB out of the directory for my project on my own laptop would be very in-convenient.

Is there a way to tell Capistrano to use a single DB location for every deployment yet still keep my DB in the same place locally? Setting the server to a production environment isn't an option as this stage, unfortunately. Something like being able to do :

```
development: 
  adapter: sqlite3
  :on local
      database: db/development.sqlite3
  :on server
      database: /webapps/rails/shared/dev.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

(At this point it's probably also worth mentioning I'm very much still learning my way around Rails).

Any of your thoughts would be most appreciated, thank you. If the only option is to set the env to production then that will have to do, but if there's a way round it that lets me keep the server as a development server, that would be great.

Jack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a step in capistrano that runs before any database stuff to create a symbolic link for whatever database file you want that points to the shared directory. This is how `logs` is set up for you. Something along the lines of this:

```
namespace :custom do
  task :symlink, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/development.sqlite3 #{release_path}/db/development.sqlite3"
  end
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", "customs:symlink"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after multiple application environments: one for staging on the server, one for development locally and eventually one for production. For a good run through, [try here](http://cjohansen.no/en/rails/multi_staging_environment_for_rails_using_capistrano_and_mod_rails).